# How do I change the properties of a <div> with a toggled class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have a `<div class="content toggle">` that I have hidden until a certain event is called, and then I add a class to it to show that it needs to be visible.

My current CSS looks like:

```
.content {
  display: none;
}

.content.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

My code for adding `.visible` looks like this:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('toggle'), function(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('visible');
});
```

But, when the class `.visible` is added, the `<div>` is still `display: none;`.  What's happening here?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Why not just remove the .content class instead?

Comment: you can inspect what rules are being applied or overridden using your browsers dev tools (F12). if you inspect this element, you should be able to see what CSS rule is setting it to `display:none` or if it has 0 width etc.

Comment: Where's your code for adding the class?  Are you adding `.visible` or `visible`?  It should be the latter for it to work properly.

Comment: please provide more code. what you posted should work fine. my quess is that a) visible isnt really applied or b) some other rule overrides it

Comment: @CbNrZvWd Just added the JS.

Comment: that should work too :-/ see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uypxnawL/

Comment: @CbNrZvWd but if you see here that's more similar to my code, it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/twpgzphh/

Comment: interesting. this works tho: https://jsfiddle.net/twpgzphh/1/ or this: https://jsfiddle.net/twpgzphh/2/

Answer (score 1):

seems like your JS selects a class called "toggle" instead of "content":

```
getElementsByClassName('toggle')
```

Comment: Yes, but it's still affecting my `<div class="content toggle">`, and makes it `<div class="content toggle visible">`.

Comment: Have you used the browsers developer tools to see which classes the DIV really has after triggering that function?

Answer (score 1):

There's 100 ways do what you want. Here's one solution.

```
   <script>
      function makeVisible() {
         var myContentDiv = document.getElementById("mycontent");
         myContentDiv.style.display = "block";
      }
   </script>
   <div id="mycontent" class="content"></div>
   <a id="mybutton" href="javascript:makeVisible()"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer, to reflect the jsfiddle.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">hi</div>
<button id='button'>toggle visible</button>
```

JS

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('content');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried this (without jQuery), and you can see that it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/twpgzphh/

Comment: Updated yours, without jQuery, please take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/twpgzphh/3/. Let me know if it works! :)

Comment: Glad I could help, edited my answer, please accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.content {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

?

Comment: Multiple things are getting the class added and it affects each of them in different ways, which is why I hesitate to do it this way.

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your display classes separate from your core class.

in jQuery:

```
$(this).toggleClass("visible hidden");
```

and the css:

```
<style>
.visible {
   display: block;
}
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
</style>
```